# CSS hamburger menu icon with different line widths

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I've created a simple hamburger menu icon where I want the middle line to be slightly shorter than the other two. Can this be done *without* creating multiple `divs`? My current solution is done by multiple `box-shadows`, **[see my working example](https://jsfiddle.net/topr/pqwp90e7/)**.

This is what I have vs what I want to achieve:

[image]

My CSS:

```
.menu-button:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #0e3c89;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 0 0 #0e3c89, 0 16px 0 0 #0e3c89;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this can be done without extra markup. Here is one way you could do it:

```css
.menu-button {
    width: 20px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #0e3c89;
    margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.menu-button:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 28px;
    height: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 -8px 0 0 #0e3c89, 0 8px 0 0 #0e3c89;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-button"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to make this shape with minimum possible markup:

1. Create a element with specific `width` / `height` having top / bottom borders.
2. Use `linear-gradient()` to draw the central bar and control its size with `background-size` and position with `.background-position` css properties.

**Necessary HTML:**

Only single element (Possibly having a class):

```
<div class="menu-button"></div>
```

**Necessary CSS:**

```
.menu-button {
  // draws the central bar
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0e3c89, #0e3c89) no-repeat;
  background-position: center left;
  background-size: 85% 4px;

  // draws the top / bottom bars
  border: solid #0e3c89;
  border-width: 4px 0;

  height: 24px;
  width: 28px;
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Opener Image]

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.menu-button {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0e3c89, #0e3c89) no-repeat;
  background-position: center left;
  background-size: 85% 4px;
  border: solid #0e3c89;
  border-width: 4px 0;
  height: 24px;
  width: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-button"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion (using flexbox):

```css
.hamburger {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 23px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top: 6px solid #0e3c89;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #0e3c89;
}

.hamburger::before {
  content: "";
  width: 70%;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #0e3c89;
}
```

```html
<span class="hamburger"></span>
```